# C++ infinite loop based on input

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main (){   
    
    unsigned int x{0};
    unsigned int y{0};
    unsigned int i{1};
    unsigned int power{1}; 

    cout<<"Input x and y: "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cin >>y;

    while (i<y || i == y)
    {
        power *= x;
        ++i;
        cout << power <<endl;
    }
    

 }
```

output:

```
Input x and y: 
10
5
10
5
10
5
```

and it would keep running to infinity, but if I remove the = condition it runs, why is that happening.

Comment: Works as expected [here](https://ideone.com/B41Nxt)

Comment: What's your `x` and `y` input? It did run for me.

Comment: `i<y || i == y` can simply be written as `i <= y`

Comment: *"but if I remove the = condition it runs"* Did you do typo with `i = y` instead of `i == y` locally?

Comment: You want calculate the power ?

Comment: I can't picture any input that would result in that output - there is no integer `x` such that `10 * x == 5` and `5 * x == 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find different solution:

**Solution 1:**

*Simple "while" for calculate the power*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int main (){   
    
    unsigned int x{0};
    unsigned int y{0};
    unsigned int i{1};
    unsigned int power{1}; 

    cout<<"Input x (base)  and y (exponent): "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cin >>y;

    while (i<=y)
    {
        power *= x;
        ++i;
    }
    cout << power <<endl;

 }
```

**Solution 2:**

Simple "for" for calculate the power

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int main (){   
    
    unsigned int x{0};
    unsigned int y{0};
    unsigned int i{1};
    unsigned int power{1}; 

    cout<<"Input x (base)  and y (exponent): "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cin >>y;


    for(int i=0; i < y; i++)
        power *= x;
        
    cout << power <<endl;

 }
```

**Solution 3:**

Simple "while" for calculate the power with "debug output".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int main (){   

    unsigned int x{0};
    unsigned int y{0};
    unsigned int i{1};
    unsigned int power{1}; 

    cout<<"Input x (base)  and y (exponent): "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cin >>y;

    while (i<=y)
    {
        power *= x;
        cout<<i<<" -> " <<power<<endl;
        ++i;
    }
    cout << power <<endl;

 }
```